# Harrison Python Web Programming stuck on scraping RSS feeds (3.4.2)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, rss, lxml

I am following a Python course with 'Harrison Python Web Programming', and have got stuck on the 'Scraping RSS feeds (3.4.2)' section.

When I install BeautifulSoup4, it seems to install fine, but then when I execute the code I run into this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owen/Desktop/Owen/Electronics/Code/Python Web Programming XML.py", line 6, in <module>
    xml= BeautifulSoup(req, 'xml')
  File "C:\Users\Owen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?`

I have had a look around on the net, and have been told that I need to install `lxml`. But when I do that I run into this error:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/

Comment: `lxml` and `beautifulsoup4` both have wheels, still getting the same error. What are you suggesting?

Comment: lxml has an "unofficial" wheel, are you using that? Check the MS Windows section on: http://lxml.de/installation.html

Comment: Perfect! Thank you jinks, anyone know why the official don't work?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing the `"Error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"` because pip assumes you have a MS Visual C++ compiler installed. (If I'm not mistaken, pip also assumes that you magically have the correct version of the compiler as well.)

[Futher reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/18045219#18045219)

Using a precompiled wheel will often work. However, per lxml:

> If you fail to build lxml on your MS Windows system from the signed
>   and tested sources that we release, consider using the binary builds
>   from PyPI or the [unofficial Windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) that Christoph Gohlke
>   generously provides.